# How to rewrite `-r-------- 1 apache apache a.txt`?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

There's a file `-r--------  1 apache  apache a.txt`.
Now,I open `GNOME Terminal 3.14.3`. Even `su root` cannot rewrite this file.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo chmod 777 a.txt
sudo cp a.txt /home/your-username/a.txt
```

Now make your changes and run the following commands:

```
sudo chmod 777 a.txt
sudo cat /home/your-username/a.txt > a.txt
sudo chmod 400 a.txt
```

Note: Make sure that you replace /home/your-username with your home folder and you set the working directory to the directory where the file is in.